# Change custom UIView to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, xib, custom-view

In general:
I got a custom UIView with a xib file as subview on a UIViewController. I add the subview programmatically in my controller.

In my UIViewController:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomSubView" owner:self  options:nil];
mySubView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
...
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Because I need to scroll on this subview, which also have an UIImageView on it, I decided to change my custom UIView into an UIScrollView.

I did the following steps:

- Changed the MyCustomSubView.xib, added an UIScrollView with Custom Class MyCustomSubView (and an UIImageView on it like before)
- Changed my MyCustomSubView class to extend UIScrollView
- Changed my MyViewController to implement UIScrollViewDelegate
- set mySubView.delegate to self(the controller)
- implemented (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView and returned the UIImageView of the subview
- enabled user interaction on the imageview and on the uiscrollview

These were my total steps I think. But as example, the viewForZoomingInScrollView method wasn't called. Also I tried to zoom in, but nothing happened.

Anyone an idea, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking briefly at the [`UIScrollView` Class Reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1), I see the following:

> The UIScrollView class can have a delegate that must adopt the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:; in addition, the maximum (maximumZoomScale) and minimum ( minimumZoomScale) zoom scale must be different.

You mentioned implementing `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`, but not `scrollViewDidEndZooming:atScale:`, nor did you mention setting `maximumZoomScale` or `minimumZoomScale`.  Try doing those things, and check back if you're still having issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read the class reference before, but after your answer I looked again at my code and now found instantly a little fail, because I implemented the scrollViewDidEndZooming wrong. Its hard that I spend 1 hour with that and after your answer I just had 1 minute. Thx!

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  Glad I could help.